# How come GetElements doesn't return direct results?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Learning Javascript for the first time and just playing around with it on Chrome,
but noticed results aren't as expected. Upon inputting:

document.getElementsByTagName("h1")

I expect to see: `<h1>tester h1 in body</h1>`

Instead, it is returning a long dropdown of "HTMLCollection [h1]".

Why is this and how I get the simplified view?

See picture here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQjmV.png)

Comment: Click on the arrow next to the `0`. That’s all you need to see. The `HTMLCollection` contains one element: `HTMLCollection[0]`.

Comment: Your result is a collection (of 1) `h1` tags.  What you are looking at is all the attributes of this element.  To get your simplified result try `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].outerHTML`

Comment: Can you tell us, what specifically you need to see? What do you mean by “simplified view”? The two answers below are just guessing things, currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the whole element with all its associated properties and methods. You can find what you're after in the `.outerHTML` property (`document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].outerHTML`).

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I try this, the output is 'undefined'

Comment: Apologies, - document.getElementsByTagName returns an array-like object, not just the one thing. If you know there's only one in the text, you can just find it with the [0] index as I've added above.

Comment: Thanks, adding [0] gave me the view I was expecting. Though, if there is more than one result, but I want to see them all in a simplified view, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Sure, but don't think of it as a 'simplified view' - the outerHTML is a specific property of the element you are finding. If you want an array of those elements, you can convert the object you get back into an array and map into the outerHTML property like this: `[...document.getElementsByTagName('h1')].map(element => element.outerHTML]`

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of function for get
one starts with getElement and one with getElements.
getElement returns one and getElements returns multiple as an array.

so you need to iterate over the element in loop to work on it.

The output you need will come from .outerHTML of one of element.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is already answered, but it may help you as you're learning to understand whats being returned by `getElementsByTagName` and similar methods.

You'll note the 's' in 'Elements', which should be a clue that the method is going to return multiple elements. In this case, ALL `HTML` elements in the document with an `H1` tag will be returned in array-like NodeList object:

```
HTMLCollection [h1]
```

To access your element, you just need to specify the index in the array that you're targeting by adding [0], or whatever index value you need, even if there's only one expected element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]
```

This is a common gotcha for learners when using the `getElementsByClassName` method as well. But if you pay attention to the plurality specified in the method name ('Elements'), and remember to specify the index value you'll be all set.